# Probability of rolling a $1$ or a $6$ on a weighted die

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

> A die is weighted so that the number $6$ comes up three times as often as any other number and all other numbers have the same probability of occurring. What is the probability of rolling a $1$ or a $6$?
>
> A. $\dfrac 23$ $\quad$  B. $\dfrac 12$  $\quad$ C. $\dfrac 38$ $\quad$  D. $\dfrac 13$ $\quad$  E. $\dfrac 14$

Please explain how you got the answer!

Comment: Any thoughts?  What is the probability of rolling a $6$?  What about a $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $6$ is three times as likely to be rolled, and the others all have equal probability, then the probability of rolling a $6$ would be $\frac 38$, and the other numbers all $\frac 18$. The probability of rolling a $1$ or a $6$ would be $$\frac 38+\frac 18=\frac 12$$